# how to insert data into the front of the table when inserting data into a database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert the data to the front of the table, but I don't know how to write the accurate sql statement, I find a lot of resources still not solve my question. I hope someone can tell me the answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no "front" of the table in SQL strictly speaking.  Just do your insert, and then if you need output in a certain order, then do a select with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.